# Not getting the employee List from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on search employee by Department Id.
I want a list of employees from database for same department Id.
I am not able to pass the parameter in stored procedure.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchEmployeeDetails_SP", sqlConn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dept_id", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = enteredDeptId;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        EmpList.Add(new EmployeeDetails()
                        {
                            Dept_ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Dept_ID")),
                            Emp_ID = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("Emp_ID")),
                            Hiredate = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Hiredate"))
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please define "not able". Is an exception thrown, an `if` or `while` not entered?

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not passed the dept_id to the procedure. Hope this will help you

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SearchEmployeeDetails_SP", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dept_id", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = enteredDeptId;
        cmd.Parameters["@dept_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EmpList.Add(new EmployeeDetails()
                    {
                        Dept_ID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Dept_ID")),
                        Emp_ID = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("Emp_ID")),
                        Hiredate = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Hiredate"))
                    });
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            return EmpList.ToList();
        }
```